# How to use Cordova-plugin-purchase to do in-app purchase with “Purchase attribution” in Cordova-Vue3 project?

Tags: cordova, vuejs3, in-app-purchase, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-purchase

I am working on a Cordova-Vue3 project and want to use the [cordova-plugin-purchase](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/tree/v13) plugin to handle the Google Play subscriptions. I need to know how to define the purchase function with the [Purchase attribution (setObfuscatedAccountId)](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/developer-payload#attribute) in the Vue3 components. Can anyone provide guidance or examples on how to do this?

Currently, I am using the [Cordova-Plugin-InAppPurchases](https://github.com/cozycodegh/cordova-plugin-inapppurchases) plugin and it works well, but it does not support the [Purchase attribution (setObfuscatedAccountId)](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/developer-payload#attribute)